# php user role not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

what is wrong with this code?
I really just want to display the current users role, but it seems impossible :-(

I have tried this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); 
 } else { }

global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'User role: ' . $current_user->role . "";
?>
```

And this:

```
    <?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();  
    printf( __( 'Netværksgruppe: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( 
    $current_user->role ) ) ;
    ?>
```

and about 100 more, but nothing seems to work...
(I have tried with plugins, php snippets, functions.php, anything)
Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user role isn't a string value you can output like that. Take a look at the [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object.

`$user->roles` is actually an *array*. Most WP installations result in each user having a single role. but there are many reasons why a user may have multiple roles. So you'll either need to output all of the roles using something like [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or just output the first role by index.

```
// Current WP_User object
$user = wp_get_current_user();

// All Roles (implode the array)
printf( 'All my roles are: %s.', implode( ', ', $user->roles ) );
    # Result: "All my roles are: administrator, custom_role, some_role."

// Or single role (only output the first result)
printf( 'My role is: %s.', $user->roles[0] );
    # Result: "My role is: administrator."
```

Comment: Additionally, here's [a WP codex page with a snippet](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata#Examples).

Comment: THis seems to be working, but not on the roles I have created. It writes the administrator but not the student a, b, c, d that I have created in WP (without plugin). 
The result now is administrator on every user, what to doo?

Comment: Then those roles aren't added to the current user properly, but administrator is. You can confirm by looking at the `wp_usermeta` table for current user's capabilities.

Comment: I have created new roles with wps own user role editor

Answer (score 0):

See documentation of get_currentuserinfo() -
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

$current_user - is object, not string. If you need email of curent user:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you friend, but it is not the email i am searching for, it is the user role, because i have assigned new roles. It is them I wish to display. Can you show me the correct code for $roles??